# hosting Odata services developed using microsoft WCF .Net framework

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, wcf, odata

I created Odata service using .Net framework and i'm able to access the service locally using 'localhost'. But i'm unable to access it remotely. Can i know any ways to host the service in internet.I tried the procedure as mentionedin http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728288.aspx
but it didn't solved my issue.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I think you will need to provide more details like, do you get an error? If so what error?